# How can I ensure all processes are done writing to an output queue before proceeding?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm working on understanding multiprocessing in Python. Currently, I'm trying to improve my understanding of queues and processes.

What I'm trying to do is iterate over some data, sending chunks of it to be analyzed by previously spawned worker functions.
As indicated in the MWE below, the results are sometimes computed before the workers have had time to react to their data. What would be a good way to ensure that my workers are done before I proceed? I am aware of the Pool.join() method - is there something similar to be done here? I know that Pool.map can do this in chunks, but it seems if I give it an iterator over a large file (which is the end goal here), it still tries to read in the whole file first, rather than starting immediately on working on the chunks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import queue

def worker(inqueue, outqueue, name = None):
    if name is None:
        name = mp.current_process().pid
    print("Spawned", name)

    while True:
        # Read data from input queue
        data = inqueue.get()

        # Kill worker if input is None
        if data is None:
            print("Killing", name)
            return None

        # Compute partial sum and put on output queue
        print(name, "got data:", data)
        partial_sum = sum(data)
        outqueue.put(partial_sum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = range(1, 101)
    buffer_size = 7  # Number of items for each partial sum

    inqueue = mp.Queue()
    outqueue = mp.Queue()

    # Define and start processes
    processes = []
    for i in range(1,5):
        p = mp.Process(target = worker,
                       args = (inqueue, outqueue, "process %d" % i,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    # Run through numbers, periodically sending buffer contents to a worker
    buffer = []
    for num in numbers:
        buffer.append(num)
        if len(buffer) >= buffer_size:
            inqueue.put(buffer)
            buffer = []
        #

    # Send remaining contents of buffer to worker
    inqueue.put(buffer)

    # Kill all processes
    for _ in range(len(processes)):
        inqueue.put(None)

    # Compute running sum as long as output queue contains stuff
    remaining = True
    running = 0

    #time.sleep(1)  # Output is as expected if we sleep for 1 sec

    while remaining:
        try:
            temp = outqueue.get(False)
            running += temp
        except queue.Empty:
            remaining = False
        #

    print(running)  # 0 if no sleep. 5050 if sleep.
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: You are using this Sentence: `# Kill all processes`

What you are doing is **not** *killing* a `Process`.
You **stopping** a `Process` gracefully at a controlled Point!
Killing meant interrupting at a unpredictable Point of execution which is **not** recommended.

---

> **Question**: ... to ensure that my workers are done

Use the `Process.is_alive()` method to do that.

```
while any([p.is_alive() for p in processes]):
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

> [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)
>
> ```
> is_alive()
> ```
>
> Return whether the process is alive.
>     Roughly, a process object is alive from the moment the start() method returns until the child process terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You can often simplify this type of code -- and avoid the need for managing the in-queue and out-queue yourself -- by taking advantage of `Pool.map` or `Pool.imap`.

A simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def work_items(n, step):
    for i in range(0, n, step):
        yield range(i, min(n, i + step))

def worker(item):
    return sum(item)

with Pool(4) as pool:
    total = sum(pool.imap(worker, work_items(101, 7)))
    print(total)   # 5050
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have given up trying to use `multiprocessing.Pool` because it *is* possible to send work asynchronously and incrementally to the the processes within, and it allows the processing to be simplified.

Below is an example of using one based on the code in your question. Note its use of a `multiprocessing.Event` to tell the `Pool` processes to quit—a technique you may also be able to use to solve the problem with your current approach.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import queue

def worker(args):
    event, inqueue, outqueue, name = args
    print("{} started".format(name))

    while not event.is_set():  # not stopped
        data = inqueue.get()  # Read data from input queue
        print(name, "got data:", data)
        # Compute and put partial sum on output queue
        partial_sum = sum(data)
        outqueue.put(partial_sum)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    CHUNK_SIZE = 7  # Number of items for each partial sum
    NUM_PROCESSES = 4
    numbers = range(1, 101)  # Data to process.

    mgr = mp.Manager()
    inqueue = mgr.Queue()
    outqueue = mgr.Queue()
    event = mgr.Event()

    # Create and start the processes in a processing pool
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=NUM_PROCESSES)
    args = [(event, inqueue, outqueue, "Process %d" % (i+1,))
                for i in range(NUM_PROCESSES)]
    pool.map_async(worker, args)
    pool.close()

    # Put numbers to process into the work queue in chunks
    for i in range(0, len(numbers), CHUNK_SIZE):
        chunk = list(numbers[i: i+CHUNK_SIZE])
        print('putting data:', chunk)
        inqueue.put(chunk)

    while not inqueue.empty():  # All data processed?
        time.sleep(.001)
    event.set()  # signal all data processed
    pool.terminate()

    # Total all the values in output queue
    final_sum = 0
    while True:
        try:
            temp = outqueue.get_nowait()
            final_sum += temp
        except queue.Empty:
            break

    print('final sum:', final_sum)  # 5050 if correct
```

Output from a typical test run:

```
putting data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
putting data: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
putting data: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
putting data: [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
putting data: [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
putting data: [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]
putting data: [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
putting data: [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]
putting data: [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
putting data: [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
putting data: [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77]
putting data: [78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84]
putting data: [85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91]
putting data: [92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
putting data: [99, 100]
Process 1 started
Process 2 started
Process 1 got data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Process 1 got data: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
Process 1 got data: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
Process 2 got data: [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
Process 2 got data: [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
Process 1 got data: [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]
Process 3 started
Process 2 got data: [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
Process 1 got data: [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]
Process 2 got data: [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
Process 3 got data: [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
Process 1 got data: [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77]
Process 2 got data: [78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84]
Process 4 started
Process 1 got data: [85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91]
Process 2 got data: [92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
Process 3 got data: [99, 100]
final sum: 5050
```